# Multithreading Options

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am having a bit of a dilemma, or rather, am unsure which technology/method to use and how. What I am trying to accomplish is basically this:

Hit a web service, multiple times at once, on different threads, based on the number of "calls" I have to make to that web service. The "calls" of course here are to the exact same web service method, with different parameters for each call.

Because I am working with Web Services, I am assuming that these services are setup for multiple calls at once, and therefore, I should be able to maximize speed and efficiency by splitting the work on multiple threads and making multiple calls at once.

Right now, I am basically creating a set number of background workers from my main thread, and executing the same code on each BGWKR. I am not fond of this because I am copy-pasting the code in each BGWKR `DoWork()` method, and reading the parameters from a list that is partitioned according to how many BGWKRs I have... so I am limiting myself to the amount of BGWKRs I create, and have to partition my list accordingly. Of course, I also keep a log for each call made, on each BGWKR, and merge those together when they all exit through my own "sync" mechanism...

Ideally what I would like to do is the logical opposite. That is: partition my list according to a maximum number of items per partition (e.g.: 10 per), and then fire off the number of threads needed to make the calls for each partition created this way.

As an example result I am looking for, for a 10 per requirement:
100 items total yields
10 threads with 10 items in each

150 items total yields
15 threads with 10 items in each

It would also be nice if I didn't have to manually sync all of the logs at the end too!

So my question is: how do I accomplish this? I've heard talks about Task Parallel Library, but after looking into it more, that seems geared towards utilizing the maximum number of cores to accomplish a single task?

Is there a way to do what I want without too much manual intervention and copy-pasting of code blocks?

Something like this:

```
List<Partition> Partitions = (Split Total Items into partitions of 10);

For(int i=0; i<Partitions.Count; i++)
{
    SomeThreadType trd = new SomeThreadType()
    trd.CodeToExecute =>
    {
        ForEach(Item in Partitions[i])
        {
            SyncedLogEntries[i].AddRange(Call Web Service(Item));
        }
    }
    trd.WaitManager = SomeSyncMechanism();
    trd.Start();
 }

 WaitManager.OnAllThreadsDone += SomeEventHandlerMethod();
```

I know this is a very crude version, and that there might be more integrated ways of doing what I want, but it gives a good idea as to what I'd like to accomplish. So is it possible, and if so, how?